# SSRS Report local machine execution error

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I have multiple reports to upgrade from SSRS-2005 to SSRS-2013 Visual Studio! Upgrade task have worked perfectly.

Also changed new database server(remote) connection as an "TargetServer URL" of project property.
While executing report in local machine below error is getting display.

[image]

Problem is why this error occurring even I am able to deploy the project without any error in Visual Studio.

could anyone please suggest anything to resolve this?

Comment: Check you report dataconnection?

Comment: @DaniDev: Yes already checked, all set!

Comment: next thing to check is your permission configuration access to reports and Dataconnections are assigned to users or groups specific to the domain the report server is on

Comment: @DaniDev: Yes you are right! I just checked and found that My user dont have permission access to reports! could you please tell that from where i can assign permission? Dont mind but as an answer so I can vote that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having user access issue that I have found by the help of "DaniDev".
So just need to assign access to local machine user.

**※ To add a user or group to a system role**

STEP:1 →Start the web portal.

STEP:2 →Select the gear icon in the upper right.

STEP:3 →Select "Site Settings".

STEP:4 →Select Security tab.

STEP:5 →Select Add group or user.

STEP:6 →In Group or user, enter a Windows domain user or group account in this format: `domain\account`.

STEP:7 →Select a system role, and then select OK.

STEP:8 →Roles are cumulative, so if you select both System Administrator and System User, 
    a user or group will be able to perform the tasks in both roles.

STEP:9 →Repeat to create assignments for additional users or groups.

★Reference URL: [Grant User: Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/grant-user-access-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are saying it sounds as though, in your new hosting enviornment, you dont have the proper users/Groups added and assigned to the reports

I'm not certain how the SSRS admin console looks like but, the should be a users/groups tab or option. Make sure to add the users that are either part of the (Windows) domain you are in or that you configure specifically for this instance of SSRS. Then you can add those users to either each report or the entire report folder.

Comment: hey! thanks for your advice and i applied it in adding new user as i have described in above answer! & it worked like charm! so thank you again for your idea!